# Reloading an Ext.data.Store model?

Tags: extjs, model, store, reload, extjs3

I'm trying to fix some issue with an ExtJs website but not sure how to proceed. Basically, I have a form that loads an `Ext.data.Store` model. For new models, the model object initially doesn't have an ID. Once it's saved an ID is assigned to it by the webservice.

The problem is that this `Ext.data.Store` model is not being reloaded after saving, so it stays without an ID, which causes some problems later on.

So is there any way to force ExtJs to reload the store model after saving? I checked the documentation of `Ext.data.Store` but cannot see any "reload()" or "refresh()" method. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. ExtJs has a logic to replace models with `phantom` flag with the new copies received from the store after update procedure. Chec couple things:

Make sure you have correctly specified `idProperty` in the model. This is how ExtJs will detect whether record is new or not.

Make sure your store returns properly new/updated records in the response message.

Make sure your data reader properly parses these records in the response message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using ExtJs 3.4 so I'm actually dealing with a Store that contains Records but it seems it's the same principle. I see that the reader is being called the first time a record is loaded. However, it's not called again after a record is saved. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Not really. Didn't have enough experience with 3.4. Try to read the code to see what happens after response is received.